# Run command if a program is run at a specific time of day?

Tags: c#, clock

I'd like to write a program that when executed will check for the system time, and if the system time is say... between 5pm and 8pm (or between 17:00 and 20:00) it will run a command, else it will just exit.

I'm having a harder time than i thought i would figuring out how to do this. all i've found out so far is that i can get the current date and time in a readable output from

```
DateTime.Now
```

but i have no idea how i can order the program to run commands depending on what time of day it is (regardless of date.) and using DateTime.Now to get the time then playing around with the string until it gives me a double or int for what time it is seems like a rather "uncool" way of doing it

Comment: You might consider using another tool to accomplish what you want, like the task scheduler on windows, or cron on *nix systems.

Comment: You might want to consider just using the OS scheduler for this. You can set it up to run an application every day at a certain time. Else Carlos's answer below is the right track.

Comment: Who triggers the execution of the program?

Comment: I don't like the OS scheduler, this is way easier for me. lets say i want it to check the time at startup and execute a command depending on the time, i'm more comfortable with doing it this way and adding the .exe as a startup program in msconfig than using the OS scheduler, call me eccentric if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be something like this, to check for example if current hour is between 17 and 20.
Just change the values:

```
 if (DateTime.Now.Hour > 17 && DateTime.Now.Hour < 20)
 { 
   //Do stuff
 }
```

**Edit:** If you want to include the hours in the if sentence use >= <=

```
 if (DateTime.Now.Hour >= 17 && DateTime.Now.Hour <= 20)
 { 
   //Do stuff
 }
```

Comment: Actually this will only work between 6pm and 8pm. You want `>= 17`

Comment: Yeah. I was editing it. Maybe he needs to include that hours.

Comment: hehe i already knew that, but it rarely hurts to be a perfectionist.

Answer (score 0):

If you need finer control over the timing, such as including minutes in your "window", then use two TimeSpan's like this:

```
TimeSpan start = new TimeSpan(17, 30, 0); // 5:30 pm
TimeSpan stop = new TimeSpan(20, 45, 0); // 8:45 pm
if (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay >= start && DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay <= stop)
{
    // ... do something ...
}
```